# Problem with GPS old location

Tags: gps, python, modem, at-commands

I wrote a GPS driver which sends and reads AT commands. I send the `AT+CGPS=1,1` command to get the GPS location and if there is no answer I send `AT+CGPS=0`.

It works well for an hour (the GPS sends the right location) and then the GPS starts returning the same (old) location.

Do you maybe know what can be the reason (the voltage on the antenna is correct)?

I use the SIM7600 GPS driver (same code as [here](https://github.com/VicDominguez/SIM7600X-4G-HAT/blob/459148d33e873c7b5812dd75678b8444aa79721f/Raspberry/python/GPS/GPS.py)) in an infinite loop.

Comment: Welcome! Please embed schematic and code used.

Comment: Is the GPS maybe switching to some power-saving mode? Can you get the NMEA output? That would probably provide a lot more info about the state of the GPS.

Comment: What  is the GPS model? Have you tried it with a different GPS? Do other GPS functions still work if accessed by code? If you monitor the GPS current does it change current drain at about one hour? If you power the GPS off and on at say 15 minutes does it then stop working at 1 hour or 1hr 15m?

Comment: I have another (more precise) IMU/GPS unit and it shows the correct location. I did not try other functions and did not monitor the current drain but definitely will, as well as NMEA output and accuracy settings. Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

GPS chips often have a feature where the position remains static when it is (seemingly) sitting in the same location.

That is because in case the device is not moving early GPS's would render positions "jumping" around the actual location.  There are several reasons for that, but it's something that can be observed with the position.

So a feature was introducted to keep the same position so that it actually looks like the GPS is sitting still.

If the GPS time is updating, then you are likely "suffering" from that feature.  Sometimes there is an option to turn it on or off.  I did not find the option for the SIM7600 .  Possibly `AT+CGPSHOR` (accuracy setting) impacts this behavior.

ANOTHER REASON could be that your GPS really has bad reception, but that is not what I think.